# Problem with TreeForm

Tags: combinatorics, trees

I am having an issue with the command `TreeForm`.

Suppose I have a list `L` of lists I would like to apply `TreeForm` to:

```
L = Groupings[{0,0,0,0}, {2, Orderless}]
```

> {{{{0, 0}, 0}, 0}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}

I do not understand why the following two lines of code return different trees:

```
TreeForm[{{{0, 0}, 0}, 0}]
TreeForm[L[[1]]]
```

The second one is truncated at some depth, with one node labelled "{0,0}".

Comment: I no loner have the issue if I replace 0 by a symbol a.

Comment: Right, the reason is that symbolic arrays cannot be packed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer may be that `Groupings` tries to give its output (or parts of if) as `PackedArray` if possible. And TreeForm was instructed not to unpack `PackedArray`s. See here:

```
L = Groupings[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {2, Orderless}];
a = {{{0, 0}, 0}, 0};
b = L[[1]];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[a[[1, 1]]]
Developer`PackedArrayQ[b[[1, 1]]]
```

returns

```
(* False *)
(* True *)
```

Or at least `TreeForm` does not unpack `PackedArray`s that are leaves of a nodes that are not themselves `PackedArray`s. Pure `PackedArray`s are displayed "correctly".